# Declaring classes in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

I understand that, in Android, all activities must be declared within the manifest. Is this true to all .java files in the project?

I have a few classes that aren't activities (not directly related to an UI) and i'm unsure whether I need to declare them in the manifest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, only activities. All other java classes don't have to be declared in the manifest file to be used. If you're having contentproviders or services in your application you also need to declare them in the manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to declare all classes in the manifest. Things you do need to declare are Activities, Services and ContentProviders.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that, it is false! you only just have to put some informations like ContentProviders and Authorisations

Answer (score 1):

Angelo,

To answer your question, you must declare any class that is a static Android Application Component. This means all Activities, ContentProviders, and Services. This also includes static BroadcastRecievers that are not manually registered in code. Finally, you must also declare any external Android Library Projects.

The idea is essentially this: If you want the System or User or External Application to be able to use your object, it **must** be declared. Anything that has a UI (i.e. Activity) is a given in there... BroadcastRecievers are the most flexible in this regard, as they can be built, registered, and enabled dynamically. However, they will only run if the application is running, if created in this manner.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic